# How to disable a specific Proguard/R8 rule for a third-party library

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I am using `minifyEnabled true` in *build.gradle* (for obfuscation and size reduction purposes).

I have these *proguard-rules.pro*:

```
-keep class com.some3rdpartylibrary.** { *; } // otherwise it crashes

# repack obfuscated classes into single package so it would be hard to find their original package
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification // this one is causing run-time crash in the 3rd party library
```

How can I tell proguard/R8 to `dontallowaccessmodification` just for `com.some3rdpartylibrary.**`?

Comment: I am from the R8 team. It is not possible to limit the scope of `-allowaccessmodification`. It is a global flag. The current implementation of `-allowaccessmodification` in R8 will make all non-kept members public, and that can cause issues with package-private final methods that can result in runtime errors - probably what you are seeing. Right now keeping the methods causing issues is the only workaround. If possible open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938? Maybe with some more details on the runtime error.

Comment: @sgjesse How can I keep the method? Error is `Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Method void com.some3rdpartylibrary.screens.payoutCard.presentation.cardInput.presentation.CardInputViewModel.clear() overrides final method in class Lxf; (declaration of 'com.some3rdpartylibrary.screens.payoutCard.presentation.cardInput.presentation.CardInputViewModel' appears in base.apk)`.

Comment: To just keep `com.some3rdpartylibrary.screens.payoutCard.presentation.cardInput.presentation.CardInputViewModel.clear()` you can use `-keep class com.some3rdpartylibrary.screens.payoutCard.presentation.cardInput.presentation.CardInputViewModel { clear(); }`. Does that single keep solve the problem?

Comment: @sgjesse interestingly the crash persists, with the same log message. If I remove `-allowaccessmodification` it works. Also, since I have the rule `-keep class com.some3rdpartylibrary.** { *; }` shouldn't this already include `com.some3rdpartylibrary.screens.payoutCard.presentation.cardInput.presentation.CardInputViewModel { clear(); }`?